# Angular: Set a default value in ng-repeat if an item's property does not exist

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is it possible possible during ng-repeat that if the current item does not have a certain property, I assign a default value for it, something like that:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-init="item.prop = item.prop || default value"></div>
```

Comment: can you explain why you need this? and also, are you try your code?

Comment: @Grundy I added a new property for an existing project and I need objects that are already created to have a default value.

Comment: you can fill it in js code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to *show* default value, it would be:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div>{{ item.prop || 'Nothing' }}</div>
</div>
```

If you want to *assign* it for each object of array, then do it in your controller:

```
angular.forEach($scope.items, function (item) {
    item.prop = item.prop || 'Nothing';
});
```

Comment: I did that but I used item.prop = item.hasOwnProperty('prop ') ? item.prop : true;

Answer (score 0):

I make some change from your code, and it just works ...

from:

```
item.prop = item.prop || default value
```

to:

```
new_prop = item.prop || default value
```

and use the new_prop instead of item.prop

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>
  angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.list = [
      {name: 'a', idx: 1},
      {name: 'b'},
      {name: 'c', idx: 2},
    ];  
  });
</script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="each in list" ng-init="idx = each.idx || 0">
    <span ng-bind="idx"></span>
    <span ng-bind="each.name"></span>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: but what if i want to assign this value to that object when the users saves to database for example?

Answer (score 0):

**Best Practice**

It depends where you are getting your data from, if you are getting it with a http request you should probably have default values in your database.

**Alternative 1**

Use angular's built in default with the pipe character, example with `ng-bind` below.

```
<span ng-bind="myVariable || 'My default value'"></span>
```

**Alternative 2**

You could write an if statement within a loop before your $scope is set. Something like this will go in your controller.

```
if ($scope.data.someData == null){
  $scope.data.someData = yourDefultValue
}
```

This is just a generalisation you will have to adapt it into your code but I would advise putting default values in your database. Its easy to do and should be done if there is a default value you want.